# Calculating specific heat capacity from entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I'm currently struggling with a specific thermodynamics problem.
I'm given the entropy of a system (where A is a constant with fitting physical units): $$S(U,V,N)=A(UVN)^{1/3}$$

I'm asked to calculate the specific heat capacity at constant pressure $C_p$ and at constant volume $C_V$.
I know that the two are given by the following equation:
$$C_P=T \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{N,P}$$
$$C_V=T \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{N,V}$$

I've tried to calculate a expression for the entropy in terms of the temperature $T$ by calculating $$\left (\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)=\frac{1}{T}=\frac{1}{3}(NV)^{1/3}U^{-2/3}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{S}{U}$$

but I think i'm going in a circle with this approach.

I guess I'm also having problems with the notation $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{N,P}$ vs $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{N,V}$. I know that this should mean "partial derivative of $S$ with respect to $T$ with constant $N$ and $P$ or $V$". But I'm not quite sure on how to evaluate that mathematically. For me personally, if I were to evaluate this two partial derivatives, they would be equal to eachother. But this can't be really true because of the relationship $$C_P-C_V=\frac{TV\alpha_P^2}{\kappa_T}$$

It would be awesome if anyone could give me starting point for this kind of problem because I'm kinda stuck with my method right now. Any help would be very much appreciated